# Get the input data of a transaction with web3j

Tags: transactions, web3j, java, calldata

How can I retrieve transaction details (including the input data) from a txHash using Web3j?

[image]

I tried the following method:

```java
public void buscarHhash(Web3j web3, String txHash) throws IOException {
    String inputdata;

    EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = null;
    Request<?, EthTransaction> transactionReceipt = web3.ethGetTransactionByHash(txHash);
    transactionReceipt.send().getTransaction()
            .ifPresent(tx -> {
                inputdata = tx.getInput();
            });
}
```

This method does not seem to work, and I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Does anyone know how to do it? Not necessarily with the method that I used.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're having appears to be from your handling of the optional value through a lambda function. You could perhaps try it the following way (without the use of a lambda function):

```java
String inputdata;

Optional<Transaction> tx = web3.ethGetTransactionByHash(txHash).send().getTransaction();

if (tx.isPresent()) {
    inputdata = tx.get().getInput();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I am now receiving this data "receive ===> 0x070ec83b000000000000000000000000000000000000 - ad infinitum" and I wanted to know if you could recommend me to decode them or it might be possible to receive them as the "input data" image shows.

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps this can help https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/489

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me to get uint and the address, but with the chain I could not: /